# Getting Total Sales data in mysql across tables. query timing out

Tags: mysql

Getting Total Sales data.

I have a database on mysql hosted on godaddy with the following tables.

1. Customer_data - custcode, name, etc. (about 450 rows)
2. delivery_data - date, invoice no, quantity, etc. (about 800 rows per month)

I need to get a total sales data for all customers in a month. (ideally for different month ranges which will be input by user to analyse trends).

```
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Customer Name | Jan-18 | Feb-18 | Mar-18 | Apr-18 | May-18 | Jun-18 |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ABC           |   30   |   50   |   30   |   80   |   70   |  140   |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| DEF           |   40   |   50   |   130  |  180   |   70   |  140   |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
.....
```

I have tried doing this -

1. Php with looped json - The query times out as there is just too much data to process
2. Excel VBA - It takes a few hours to run the query on the server and all other operations come to a standstill.

What could be the best way to get this data in a more efficient way?

Edit 1 -

The SQL QUERY

```
while ($year<2017){
    $months=0;
    while ($months<12){
        $cust_code=mysql_result($result2,$no,"code");
        $sqlquery3="select ifnull(sum(a.quantity),0) as total_quantity
                from delivery_line a, delivery_main b 
            where 
                a.item REGEXP 'INDOX|MEDOX|INDNIT|INDCO2|ARGON'
                and a.del_no=b.no 
                and a.series=b.series
                and b.cust_code='$cust_code'
                and month(b.date_added)=($months+1)
                and year(b.date_added) = ($year)";
        $result3=mysql_query($sqlquery3);
        $count3=mysql_num_rows($result3);
        $quantity=mysql_result($result3,0,"total_quantity");
        echo "<td>".$quantity."</td>";
    $months++;
    }
    $year++;
}
```

Comment: You should include the query you ran.  Most likely you would want to do the heavy lifting on your database server and not in PHP.

Comment: What do you mean by total sales? Is it the quantity or what?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - the query is running on the database server, but since this query is getting executed 400 (no of customers) * 12 times (once per month in a year), it does not execute completely and the page times out.

Comment: @cdaiga - i have added the SQL query. The total sales is sum(quantity)

Comment: @nk369 Why you don't you cache the results of this query so that you don't have to keep running it?

Answer (score 1):

The table `delivery_data` needs to have a foreign key referencing `customer_data` and then you simply

```
SELECT * from delivery_data a INNER JOIN customer_data b WHERE
a.custcode = b.custcode AND MONTH(b.date) = 5;
```

Where the number 5 is the month May.

Make sure you have proper indices setup on the columns you are either joining on or using as a conditional. Namely a.del, b.no, a.series, b.series, b.cust_code, b.date_added.

The regular expression on a.item could be the killer but an index won't do you any good there unless you can utilize the start of the field as an anchor, i.e

```
"LIKE 'NEEDLE%'"
```

or

```
"REGEXP '^(NEEDLE)|...'"
```

Comment: i have added the query in the original question. it is quite close to what you have said. But i need to run it for 400 customers for each month of the year and the server does not seem to be able to handle it

Comment: It shouldn't choke on this. Make sure you have proper indices setup on the columns you are either joining on or using as a conditional, i.e:

Comment: You probably would want to do some sort of conditional aggregation/pivot to generate monthly stats.  And also don't use `SELECT *`, list out what you want to select.

Comment: The * here is just for illustration purposes and in any event the performance impact of it should be negligible. A group by aggregate could be good but I would recommend fixing any performance problems in this simpler variant first before attempting that!